# fix-permissions.sh for Drupal 8

Tags: 8, security

With Drupal 7, when I upload a project from local to server, I usually run fix-permisions shell script to change owner and permissions of folder/files.

Is provided in :
https://www.drupal.org/node/244924#script-based-on-guidelines-given-above

This script, may not work with Drupal 8, I had some trouble when running it.

Is there something similar to Drupal 8 version?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! It's always a good idea to see if the problem has been solved before, by googling "Drupal 8 fix permissions script" I found, https://gist.github.com/GreenSkunk/c19b450a6060c8e6e59877a6b1e5f7a8. Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tested it? This script (that I saw, as u said, googling) is not official and no posted in Drupal sites. If someone knows it works ok  would be great. Thanks

Comment: Yep, 404 after running it. I,m trying to know if the problem is on my server config, drupal files, script or where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after some tries and fixes in Server config, I solve the problem running the shell script provided in:

https://www.drupal.org/node/244924#script-based-on-guidelines-given-above

It works in version 8 correctly as it do in version 7.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a script that fixes permissions on Drupal installations: https://github.com/Metadrop/drupal-fix-permissions-script

Permissions scheme:

> The scripts tries to secure the site using the following scheme:
>
> - Code is owned by the deploy user and by the web server's group. Deploy    user can write, web server group only read.
> - Content is owned using the same scheme but the web server can write    as well.
> - Other users have no permissions on content or code.

Strategy:

> The scripts checks if the target folder is a Drupal installation and
> stops if it is not detected.
>
> Once checked, it fixes the ownership of all folder and files (because
> it is the same for content and code). Then, it fixes the code and
> later the content.
>
> The script assumes that files and private folders under sites are
> content folders.
>
> If there are content folders outside the Drupal root folder you can
> use the --files-path option and the script will take care of it.

Performance

> The script only changes the files and folder with the wrong
> permissions or ownership, making it very fast when only a few files or
> folders need a fix. For really big installations this is very
> important as other scripts apply the permissions and ownership
> regardless are needed o not.

DISCLAIMER: I'm the author of the script.